# Time-machine backup not found

Tags: backup, data-recovery, macbook-pro, time-machine, sparsebundle

My MacBook Pro died and its logic board cannot be repaired, so I will lose all of my data unless I can recover time machine backup.

Here is what is happening with the backup file. When I first saw time machine backup it created only one file - `XXX.sparsebundle`. A tech at Apple store told me that something went wrong during backup and the data was not backed up - even though the `sparsebundle` file was big: 3.4 TB.

When I clicked on this file, it mounted a folder: MacHD backup but I was not able to open this folder. I therefore ran disk utility. Somehow the time machine got activated in the process and it started to backup the computer on which I was working (not the one that died). I immediately stopped the backup process.

But now the sparsebundle file shows zero byte but the disk still has 3.4 TB data. That means the data is still there. Please help me recover the backed up data.